# Limpiar value con Onchange

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un checkbox el cual al seleccionarlo mediante Onchange le doy un value, necesito que al deseleccionarlo este value se limpie

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" value="3" onchange="mostrar(this.value);">

  if(dato=="1"){
document.getElementById("select_sh").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("2").style.display="none";
```

Lo que hago es que al seleccionarlo oculto unos div

Comment: Lo que buscas es que cuando deselecciones el Checkbox los Div se vuelvan a mostrar?

Comment: Si, exactamente eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo darle el evento `onClick`al Checkbox en lugar de usar `onChange` asi puedes crear una funcion en javascript para ocultar y mostrar los `<div>`
Te dare un ejemplo:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" value="3" onclick="mostrar(this.value);">
```

Y posteriormente con Javascript, creas una variable fuera de tu funcion con un valor, digamos en este caso 1, asi dentro de la funcion haces una condicion para checar el valor de la variable; Entrando en el primer `if()` el div se debe ocultar, le das un nuevo valor a la variable (En este caso 2) y asi podra entrar al otro `if()` para mostrar el div; La proxima vez que le des click al checkbox, se regresara el valor inicial a la variable, te dejare este ejemplo:

```
var valor = 1;
    function mostrar(val){
        if(valor == 1){
            //CODIGO PARA OCULTAR DIV
            valor = 2;
        }else if(valor == 2){
            //CODIGO PARA MOSTRAR DIV
            valor = 1;
        }
    }
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos!